# "Focal" or "focussing" exercises, when training the eyes to focus better?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

When doing certain eye exercises, such as looking at the thumb as you bring it to your nose and as you move it away from your nose, can you call them "Focal exercises","Focussing exercises" or both?

Answer (score 1):

Note: I use the AmE spelling "focusing" below.

Both "focal" and "focusing" are in use.

For "focusing" often the term is "eye-focusing exercises". This distinguishes from other types of focusing exercises, such as those used in meditation & yoga, where "focusing" refers more to focusing the **mind** on something, rather than the eyes.

"Focal" in relation to eye exercise is also often paired with another term for specificity:  focal point exercises, focal length exercises. However, there is also something called focal hand dystonia (writer's cramp) for which exercises are prescribed.

My recommendation is to use "eye-focusing exercises" (or "focal-point eye exercises" or "focal-length eye exercises") to clarify what type of **eye** exercises you are speaking of.

Incidentally, neither "focal exercise" nor "focussing exercise" occur in GoogleBooks' BrE corpus, but "focusing exercise" does!  — See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=focal%20exercise%2Cfocusing%20exercise%2Cfocussing%20exercise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfocusing%20exercise%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

Focus/Focussing exercises:

Near and far [focussing](http://www.stevenaitchison.co.uk/blog/5-eye-exercises-to-improve-your-vision/):

Instructions for Near and far focussing.

> - Sit in a comfortable position, or stand, this will only take 2-3 minutes at a time.
> - Put your thumb about 10 inches in front of you and focus on it.
> - Now focus on something else about 10 – 20 feet in front of you.
> - On each deep breath switch between focussing on your thumb and the 10-20 feet object in front of you.
> - This will strengthen the muscles in your eyes over time and improve your vision overall.

Also ,  "[tromboning](http://www.allaboutvision.com/buysmart/see_clearly.htm)" exercise:

> - had you hold a small object at arm's length, inhale, then move the object in to touch the tip of your nose. You would then exhale, look at the object, and move it back out. *"Tromboning exercises the focusing mechanism, improves control of the extraocular muscles and stimulates the flow of nutrients inside the eyes,*" according to the See Clearly Method manual.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Focal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/focal): refers to the point at which something is put into focus. Focal point.

> - Of or relating to a focus.
> - Placed at or measured from a focus.